# Quais as diferenças entre as arquiteturas MVC e REST utilizando Spring?

Tags: mvc, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Estou com duvida entre qual arquitetura utilizar MVC ou REST.

Comment: Olá. No meu entendimento MVC é para aplicações, REST é para fazer APIs, que por sua vez são utilizadas por aplicações. Depende de qual você quer fazer.

Answer (score -2):

uma aplicação rest nao se precocupa em construir uma camada view complexa para exibir os dados.

segue referencia abaixo:

"Sistemas REST costumam possuir uma implementação totalmente separada entre dados e design, sendo que até o processo de desenvolvimento de software é separado. Existem diversas características que definem um sistema como REST, mas vamos nos contentar apenas com o básico por enquanto, que é o seguinte: um sistema REST recebe uma requisição HTTP (seja ela GET, POST,  PUT, DELETE) e retorna uma resposta em formato de texto, que neste caso usaremos um formato de dados chamado JSON."

fonte: https://imasters.com.br/devsecops/a-evolucao-do-mvc-para-rest